# How can I automount devices with no desktop environment?

Tags: linux, command-line, automounting, openbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacement for halevt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11472/replacement-for-halevt)

I've installed Arch Linux on my computer and I'm not using a desktop environment.  I just have Openbox window manager installed and bit by bit I'm building up my system with necessary applications etc.  My problem is that with a DE I had the convenience of being able to access my two CD drives or my pen drive immediately - it just detected them and would mount them automatically.  The same can be said for my Windows partition that used to be detected automatically with a DE.  Why is it that with no DE this sort of functionality is no longer present?  I have my Windows partition mounting through an entry in fstab and creating a mount point in /mnt...that's all well and good but having to do the same thing or having to use the mount command in the terminal for simple things like plugging a USB pen drive in is a bit ridiculous.  Is there any way that I can get automounting functionality?

I looked around for similar questions but all of them used a DE so I couldn't really relate to them.