# Unable to unmount a partition - respawned by udev

Tags: udev, automounting, unmounting

I have set up the udev rules to automatically mount/unmount the removable devices with udev rules based on the answer to "[How to mount removable media in /media/<LABEL> automatically when inserted, without any desktop environment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44454)".

The setup works fine, but when I try to manually umount the partition it gets "respawned" by udevd ([udevadm monitor output](http://paste.ee/p/dLUml), note that it mentions only the "autounmount" script). Stopping udev helps.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to circumvent such behaviour?