# How to mount USB stick on Debian Sid?

Tags: debian, permissions, mount

I've just installed Debian Sid on my computer but I cannot mount external USB drives as you can see in the image.

[image]

> Mounting failed
>   Cannot mount "SENZATITOLO"
>   Not authorized

What should I do?

Comment: an usb memory, but also with SD

Comment: Either use `sudo` or set the `users` option for that device in /etc/fstab, so you can mount it as ordinary user.

Comment: @ott-- Probably not, I suspect OP is trying to use udisks to mount under /media. That *should* work...

Comment: What did you do to try mounting? Do you log in by typing your password in text mode or in graphics mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automount USB drives with no GUI requirement (halevt replacement)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11472/automount-usb-drives-with-no-gui-requirement-halevt-replacement)

Comment: In graphic mode as you can see ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a lightweight window manager. I've had this problem before in another such window manager. So it sounds like a problem with polkit to me. Does your system have a directory called `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/`? If so, create a file (as root)... I use the nano text editor here. Paste into the terminal with CTRL + SHIFT + V.

```
su root
nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/55-storage.pkla
```

add the following lines:

```
[Storage Permissions]
Identity=unix-group:plugdev
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-eject;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-detach;org.freedesktop.udisks.luks-unlock;org.freedesktop.udisks.inhibit-polling;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-set-spindown
ResultAny=yes
ResultActive=yes
ResultInactive=no
```

now add yourself to the plugdev group:

```
usermod -a -G plugdev <your username>
```

logout and log back in. If it is polkit, you should be able to mount media now.

Comment: Some info on polkit or `policykit`, the [sudo of systemd](https://wiki.debian.org/PolicyKit) in `debian`. It is for mount/eject a removable media (CD/DVD, USB keys...) among others.

Comment: I got `Not Authorized to perform operation` and I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1199102/321926) and it worked, I added my user to the `plugdev` group. Did not have to logout.