# Debian stretch asks for root password in order to mount usb disks after upgrade

Tags: debian, usb-drive, autofs, authorization

After `apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`, Debian Stretch started to ask for root password for external usb disks.

Creating a [/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/55-usb-mount.pkla](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66654/how-to-mount-usb-stick-on-debian-sid) file doesn't solve the problem.

How can I make external disks mounted without root password again?

Comment: Is your user still in the `plugdev` group?

Comment: yes, it is in the `plugdev` group: ```id |  tr ',' '\n' | grep plugdev
# => 46(plugdev)```

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this before. While I do not have the full answer, this is a workaround I use

I installed `udisks2` or maybe it was before there.

I have purged whatever other mounting programs that I had for external pen-drives while making sure `mount` package is there.

What I do is this every time :-

```
$udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
```

Similarly when work is finished then :-

```
$udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1
```

mount/unmount - the action that is desired. When you want to use the disk, use mount

-b = telling/sharing that it is a block device

/dev/sdb1 = this is where my usb disk is mounted. You can find where your usb disk gets mounted by running `dmesg | tail`  and then use the same path in the command.

A simpler way would be to use `lsblk`

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0  93.1G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0 111.8G  0 part /home
```

The issue/bug is known and reported. See https://bugs.debian.org/767233

Hope it is useful to you.

Update 23/09/15 - Try running /bin/mount and see if you still need the root password. Although mount does not require root password AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this suggestion even didn't work for me. When I run the `... mount ...` command, root password is asked as before.

Comment: have updated the answer above, check at the end.