# Network manager does not connect to new networks

Tags: debian, networkmanager

Possibly after `apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`, the network manager does not connect to new networks, is even not showing the password which it connects already.

I tried to reinstall network manager, as [adviced in this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239214) but there is no luck.

I suspect this problem is somehow related with [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231121/debian-stretch-asks-for-root-password-in-order-to-mount-usb-disks-after-upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

As of yesterday, `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` solved this problem. As far as I can understand, the upgrade changed something so that system booted as if `... (systemd)` grub option selected in the submenu. So, the main reason should be booting the system with systemd, instead of SysVinit.