# Automount local drives on boot and hot-plug

Tags: debian, udev, automounting, udisks, hot-plug

I am trying to **automatically mount** all readable internal and external drives on **boot** and on **hot-plug** if they are not already mounted, preferably as a *non-root user*.

I cannot use `fstab` to do this because the drives change too frequently, and `udisks2` does not appear to automount devices when the user is not actually logged in locally.

I found a `udev` ruleset to accomplish something like this **[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11472/automount-usb-drives-with-no-gui-requirement-halevt-replacement)**, but I have read that mounting via `udev` rules is a **[VERY bad idea](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1113720#p1113720)** and doesn't work anyway with *systemd*.

*What would be the proper way to do this on a **headless Debian (jessie)** system*?

---

**Note:** I've created this `udev` rule, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to go about this:

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="automount_disks_END"

# Check if it is a mountable disk, skip if not
IMPORT{program}="/bin/udevadm info --query=property --name=%k"
ENV{ID_TYPE}!="disk", GOTO="automount_disks_END"
ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="", GOTO="automount_disks_END"

# Set mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="nosuid,nodev"
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_BUS}=="ata", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},rw,dmask=022,fmask=033"
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},ro,noatime,dmask=222,fmask=333"

# Mount the disk
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/su - user -c \"/usr/bin/udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/%k --options $env{mount_options} --no-user-interaction\""

# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/su - user -c \"/usr/bin/udisksctl unmount --force --block-device /dev/%k --no-user-interaction\""

# Exit
LABEL="automount_disks_END"
```

This rule doesn't solve the authorization check issue for users who are not logged in locally, either.

---

**CLARIFICATION:**

What I'm basically looking for is the functionality of `usbmount` that works for ATA devices and doesn't clutter up the `/media` directory with unused folders, in short.

---