# Proper automount on systemd Linux systems

Tags: linux, systemd, udev, automounting, hot-plug

What is the proper way to do a **boot/hot-plug** automount for **ATA** and **USB** storage devices on **Linux** systems using **systemd** *without* requiring a GUI or a user having to be logged in?

It seems that calling `mount` from a *udev* rule is **[no longer acceptable](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1113720#p1113720)** with *systemd* (so [older rules](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/) are no longer guaranteed to work), and *udisks* does not automount if the user is not logged in locally.

The method should have a way to include ***mount options***, so writability and filesystem masks can be set, as well as clean up after an "ungraceful" unmount *(i.e., yanking the device out while still in use)*.

---

**NOTE:** This is a similar question [one I posted earlier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332949/automount-local-drives-on-boot-and-hot-plug), but that question concerns a specific use case on *Debian* systems. This question is for all Linux systems using *systemd*.

Comment: Hmm... It seems that I've found the answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/766506/automount-usb-drives-with-systemd, but the shell script mentioned therein might do well with some improvements for ATA devices. I'll leave this question up for now to provide an opportunity for more answers.

Comment: The distribution doesn't make a difference. No need to write a new question.

Comment: Got it. Modified the question slightly and posted it on Server Fault instead. If answered there, will delete my questions here since both are yet to be answered.